# jenkins build failing to download dependency, even though same pom works fine locally

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jenkins

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.0.0.FINAL

...

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  spring-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  Hibernate (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)
```

But the same pom and repositories/dependencies work fine on my local dev build.
Jenkins is on an ubuntu box, all the other dependencies have worked fine.  My java home is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` and I have updated to latest version of Jenkins, in the hope it may fix problem.

My resolv.conf looks like this (i edited it using the resolvconf package)

```
GNU nano 2.2.6            File: /etc/resolv.conf

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I am using the jboss repository to download the new hibernate jar, it is defined like so in the POM :

```
<repository>
  <id>Hibernate</id>
  <name>JBoss Hibernate repository</name>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

and I also get a warning from maven/jenkins :

```
[WARNING] 
************ WARNING ************

This Maven runtime contains a LifecycleExecutor component with an incomplete configuration.

LifecycleExecutor class: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor
Missing component requirement: org.apache.maven.ConfigurationInterpolator

NOTE: This seems to be a third-party Maven derivative you are using. If so, please
notify the developers for this derivative project of the problem. The Apache Maven team is not
responsible for maintaining the integrity of third-party component overrides.
```

Comment: Maybe some cache issues? Is there a proxy between the Ubuntu box and the JBoss repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong case in the 'FINAL' part of your version numbering.
Try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Although I don't really know why it already worked locally. Maybe it's the windows case insensitive file system and you already have the artifact cached from an other project ...

Comment: oh gawd, will try it out. How embarrassing, I just tweeted kohsukekawa for help :-(

Comment: This is a nice catch, congrats @Brambo. However, I will be surprised if it solves the issue because it should be the responsibility of the artifactory to act as either case-sensitive or -insensitive. Thus it should not matter from which client you are trying to connect. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NimChimpsky I've already upvoted this answer and deleted mine. I think Brambo's assumption `you already have the artifact cached from an other project ` is the key. Which means it would fail if you deleted your local repository and re-run the build, it should fail locally as well. Otherwise I still don't get why it would not fail on your local but fail on jenkins. I don't get it because the repository that you are connecting is the same, so the behavior should be the same.

Comment: @melihcelik I'd have left your answer up for others ... thnx for help

Comment: @melihcelik once you have the artifact cached in your local file system you don't connect to the remote repository anymore. When resolving dependencies on the windows file system the case doesn't matter but on linux ubuntu it does matter.

Comment: @Brambo I know about the local repository and the cache.. What I wonder is would it still fail if `you deleted your local repository and re-run the build`? With a clean local repository, it shouldn't matter which client you use to request for a dependency, right? You request a file from server. If the server works case-sensitively, then either you request it from a Windows client (Nimchimpsky's comp.) or a linux client (jenkins) should fail. This is what I would expect.

Comment: @melihcelik I totally agree with you. I see now that I missed the _Otherwise_ in your comment I replied to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar problem reported on [jenkins forum](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/com-sun-tools-jar-1-5-is-missing-td390964.html) and the resolution offered by [Peter Liljenberg](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=86772) that worked is:

> Hi,
>   I haven't experienced this myself, but I'm guessing that your 
>   JAVA_HOME is not correct? Maybe it's pointing to a JRE instead of a 
>   JDK?
>   /Peter

It is not about the same jar being missing, but it might be related.

**UPDATE:** NimChimpsky updated the question and it turned out that the solution below does not apply. I'm keeping it since it *was* a possible solution.

Where is your [`Hibernate` repository](http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/) definition located? Is that defined in;

- The pom file of your project? In this case it should work fine on jenkins.
- `%M2_HOME%/settings.xml` file? In this case you should define the repository on the server that jenkins is running on.

Nevertheless, you can consider using a binary repository manager solution like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com) to centralize your repository management.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer stating that my first solution did not apply for your case. Maybe deleting it will be a better idea, I'll leave that decision to moderators. I also updated the answer with a reference, can you check that? If that does not work as well, I'll delete the answer entirely.